# How to add an XML node with text

Tags: xml, delphi

I can create my XML like which I need, but I have problem in small part. I can create this `<ubl:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="M2"/>` but I need in this line to host text as well, it should be like `<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="">7</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>` in one line.

This is my code:

```pascal
procedure TDlg_XRechnung.XML_erstellen;
var
  xRoot : IXMLNode;
begin
  X_Rechnung.XML.Clear;
  X_Rechnung.Active := True;
  X_Rechnung.Version := '1.0';
  X_Rechnung.StandAlone := 'yes';
  X_Rechnung.Encoding := 'UTF-8';
  X_Rechnung.Options := [doNodeAutoCreate, doNodeAutoIndent, doAttrNull];
  xRoot := X_Rechnung.AddChild('ubl:Invoice');
  xRoot.DeclareNamespace('ubl','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2');
  xRoot.DeclareNamespace('cac','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2');
  xRoot.DeclareNamespace('cbc','urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2');
//  if _Version = XRechnungVersion_122 then
//  begin
//    xRoot.DeclareNamespace('xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
//    xRoot.Attributes['xsi:schemaLocation'] := 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd';
//    xRoot.AddChild('cbc:CustomizationID').Text := 'urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:xoev-de:kosit:standard:xrechnung_1.2';
//  end else
//  begin
//    xRoot.AddChild('cbc:CustomizationID').Text := 'urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:xoev-de:kosit:standard:xrechnung_2.0'+
//         IfThen(InternalExtensionEnabled,'#conformant#urn:xoev-de:kosit:extension:xrechnung_2.0','');
//  end;
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := Edit_Rechnungsnummer.Text;
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:IssueDate').Text := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Edit_Rechnungsdatum.Date);
  if Edit_Leistungsdatum.Date > 100 then xRoot.AddChild('cbc:DueDate').Text := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', Edit_Leistungsdatum.Date);
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:InvoiceTypeCode').Text := '380'; // die verschiedenen Codes aus function
  if Trim(Edit_Bemerkung.Text) <> '' then xRoot.AddChild('cbc:Note').Text := Edit_Bemerkung.Text;
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode').Text := Edit_Waehrung_Rechnung.Text;
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:TaxCurrencyCode').Text := Edit_Waehrung_UST.Text;
  xRoot.AddChild('cbc:BuyerReference').Text := '';
//  if (_Invoice.InvoicePeriodStartDate > 100) and (_Invoice.InvoicePeriodEndDate > 100) then
//  with xRoot.AddChild('cac:InvoicePeriod') do
//  begin
//    AddChild('cbc:StartDate').Text := TXRechnungHelper.DateToStrUBLFormat(_Invoice.InvoicePeriodStartDate);
//    AddChild('cbc:EndDate').Text := TXRechnungHelper.DateToStrUBLFormat(_Invoice.InvoicePeriodEndDate);
//  end;
  if Trim(Edit_Bestellnummer.Text) <> '' then
    xRoot.AddChild('cac:OrderReference').AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := Edit_Bestellnummer.Text
  else
    xRoot.AddChild('cac:OrderReference').Text := '';

  with xRoot.AddChild('cac:AccountingSupplierParty').AddChild('cac:Party') do
  begin
    with AddChild('cac:PartyIdentification') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := '';
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyName') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:Name').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Name.Text;
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PostalAddress') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:StreetName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Adresse.Text;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AdditionalStreetName <> '' then
//        AddChild('cbc:AdditionalStreetName').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AdditionalStreetName;
      AddChild('cbc:CityName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Ort.Text;
      AddChild('cbc:PostalZone').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_PLZ.Text;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.CountrySubentity <> '' then
//        AddChild('cbc:CountrySubentity').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.CountrySubentity;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AddressLine <> '' then
//        AddChild('cac:AddressLine').AddChild('cbc:Line').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AddressLine;
      AddChild('cac:Country').AddChild('cbc:IdentificationCode').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Land.Text;
    end;
     with AddChild('cac:PartyTaxScheme') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:CompanyID').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_UST_ID.Text;
      AddChild('cac:TaxScheme').AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := 'VAT';
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyLegalEntity') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:RegistrationName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Name.Text;
      AddChild('cbc:CompanyID').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Firmenbuch.Text;
    end;
//    with AddChild('cac:Contact') do
//    begin
//      AddChild('cbc:Name').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.ContactName;
//      AddChild('cbc:Telephone').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.ContactTelephone;
//      AddChild('cbc:ElectronicMail').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.ContactElectronicMail;
//    end;
  end;
  with xRoot.AddChild('cac:AccountingCustomerParty').AddChild('cac:Party') do
  begin
    with AddChild('cac:PartyIdentification') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := '';
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyName') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:Name').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Name.Text;
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PostalAddress') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:StreetName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Adresse.Text;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AdditionalStreetName <> '' then
//        AddChild('cbc:AdditionalStreetName').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AdditionalStreetName;
      AddChild('cbc:CityName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Ort.Text;
      AddChild('cbc:PostalZone').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_PLZ.Text;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.CountrySubentity <> '' then
//        AddChild('cbc:CountrySubentity').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.CountrySubentity;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AddressLine <> '' then
//        AddChild('cac:AddressLine').AddChild('cbc:Line').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AddressLine;
      AddChild('cac:Country').AddChild('cbc:IdentificationCode').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Land.Text;
    end;
     with AddChild('cac:PartyTaxScheme') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:CompanyID');
      AddChild('cac:TaxScheme').AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := 'VAT';
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyLegalEntity') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:RegistrationName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Name.Text;
      //AddChild('cbc:CompanyID').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Firmenbuch.Text;
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:Contact') do
      begin
      AddChild('cbc:Name');
      AddChild('cbc:Telephone');
      AddChild('cbc:ElectronicMail');
    end;
  end;

  with xRoot.AddChild('InvoiceLine') do
  begin

    begin
      AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := '1';
      AddChild('InvoicedQuantity').Attributes['unitCode'] := 'M2';

    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyName') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:Name').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Name.Text;
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PostalAddress') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:StreetName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Adresse.Text;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AdditionalStreetName <> '' then
//        AddChild('cbc:AdditionalStreetName').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AdditionalStreetName;
      AddChild('cbc:CityName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Ort.Text;
      AddChild('cbc:PostalZone').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_PLZ.Text;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.CountrySubentity <> '' then
//        AddChild('cbc:CountrySubentity').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.CountrySubentity;
//      if _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AddressLine <> '' then
//        AddChild('cac:AddressLine').AddChild('cbc:Line').Text := _Invoice.AccountingSupplierParty.Address.AddressLine;
      AddChild('cac:Country').AddChild('cbc:IdentificationCode').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Land.Text;
    end;
     with AddChild('cac:PartyTaxScheme') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:CompanyID');
      AddChild('cac:TaxScheme').AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := 'VAT';
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:PartyLegalEntity') do
    begin
      AddChild('cbc:RegistrationName').Text := Edit_Rechnungsempfänger_Name.Text;
      //AddChild('cbc:CompanyID').Text := Edit_Rechnungsersteller_Firmenbuch.Text;
    end;
    with AddChild('cac:Contact') do
      begin
      AddChild('cbc:Name');
      AddChild('cbc:Telephone');
      AddChild('cbc:ElectronicMail');
    end;
  end;

  Memo_XML.Text := X_Rechnung.XML.Text;
end;
```

This is my output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<ubl:Invoice xmlns:ubl="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
  <cbc:ID></cbc:ID>
  <cbc:IssueDate>2021-03-20</cbc:IssueDate>
  <cbc:DueDate>2021-03-20</cbc:DueDate>
  <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
  <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>EUR</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
  <cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>EUR</cbc:TaxCurrencyCode>
  <cbc:BuyerReference></cbc:BuyerReference>
  <cac:OrderReference></cac:OrderReference>
  <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cbc:ID></cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
      <cac:PartyName>
        <cbc:Name></cbc:Name>
      </cac:PartyName>
      <cac:PostalAddress>
        <cbc:StreetName></cbc:StreetName>
        <cbc:CityName></cbc:CityName>
        <cbc:PostalZone></cbc:PostalZone>
        <cac:Country>
          <cbc:IdentificationCode></cbc:IdentificationCode>
        </cac:Country>
      </cac:PostalAddress>
      <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cbc:CompanyID></cbc:CompanyID>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
      <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        <cbc:RegistrationName></cbc:RegistrationName>
        <cbc:CompanyID></cbc:CompanyID>
      </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    </cac:Party>
  </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
  <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
    <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyIdentification>
        <cbc:ID></cbc:ID>
      </cac:PartyIdentification>
      <cac:PartyName>
        <cbc:Name></cbc:Name>
      </cac:PartyName>
      <cac:PostalAddress>
        <cbc:StreetName></cbc:StreetName>
        <cbc:CityName></cbc:CityName>
        <cbc:PostalZone></cbc:PostalZone>
        <cac:Country>
          <cbc:IdentificationCode></cbc:IdentificationCode>
        </cac:Country>
      </cac:PostalAddress>
      <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
        <cbc:CompanyID/>
        <cac:TaxScheme>
          <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
        </cac:TaxScheme>
      </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
      <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
        <cbc:RegistrationName></cbc:RegistrationName>
      </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
      <cac:Contact>
        <cbc:Name/>
        <cbc:Telephone/>
        <cbc:ElectronicMail/>
      </cac:Contact>
    </cac:Party>
  </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
  <ubl:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    <ubl:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="M2"/>
    <cac:PartyName>
      <cbc:Name></cbc:Name>
    </cac:PartyName>
    <cac:PostalAddress>
      <cbc:StreetName></cbc:StreetName>
      <cbc:CityName></cbc:CityName>
      <cbc:PostalZone></cbc:PostalZone>
      <cac:Country>
        <cbc:IdentificationCode></cbc:IdentificationCode>
      </cac:Country>
    </cac:PostalAddress>
    <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
      <cbc:CompanyID/>
      <cac:TaxScheme>
        <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
      </cac:TaxScheme>
    </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
    <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
      <cbc:RegistrationName></cbc:RegistrationName>
    </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    <cac:Contact>
      <cbc:Name/>
      <cbc:Telephone/>
      <cbc:ElectronicMail/>
    </cac:Contact>
  </ubl:InvoiceLine>
</ubl:Invoice>
```

So far it is ok, but I don't know how to create such an XML concerning to my code:

```xml
 <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="">7</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">297.5</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
```

I can create until `<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="">`, but when I want to add Text, I can't.

Comment: avoid with and put the created node in a variable, then you can use the .text property to set the node text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```pascal
with xRoot.AddChild('InvoiceLine') do
begin
  begin
    AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := '1';
    AddChild('InvoicedQuantity').Attributes['unitCode'] := 'M2';
  end;
  ...
end;
```

To either this:

```pascal
with xRoot.AddChild('InvoiceLine') do
begin
  AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := '1';

  with AddChild('InvoicedQuantity') do
  begin
    Attributes['unitCode'] := '';
    Text := '7';
  end;

  ...
end;
```

Or this:

```pascal
var
  n: IXMLnode;

...

with xRoot.AddChild('InvoiceLine') do
begin
  AddChild('cbc:ID').Text := '1';

  n := AddChild('InvoicedQuantity');
  n.Attributes['unitCode'] := '';
  n.Text := '7';

  ...
end;
```